# javascript foreach and jquery's .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, htmlcollection

I've wasted an entire day trying to work it out, and I think I nailed it, but still not sure what the heck :/

I have a js file, where I generate `<option>`'s for a `<select>`:

```
_htmlString = '<option value="' + __hex_value + '" data-class="' + _cbtn.substring(1, 13) + '">' + __hex_value + '</option>\n';  
jQuery("#colourtiles").append(_htmlString);
```

`#colourtiles` is an ID of a `<select>`.
I also have 3 static options in that select, inside html.

Now, in another script I'm doing this:

```
        [].slice.call( this.el.children ).forEach( function(el) {
        console.info(el);
        if( el.disabled ) { return; }

        var tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

        if( tag === 'option' ) {
            options += createOptionHTML(el);
        }
        else if( tag === 'optgroup' ) {
            options += '<li class="cs-optgroup"><span>' + el.label + '</span><ul>';
            [].slice.call( el.children ).forEach( function(opt) {
                options += createOptionHTML(opt);
            } )
            options += '</ul></li>';
        }
    } );
```

...but this only renders 3 elements, completely ignoring these added by .append().
And to be clear, when I return that `<select>` in console, it's all there.
But I've noticed, that `this.el.children.length` is ...3!

So it looks like 1) jQuery isn't updating .length, and 2) forEach() relies on it, therefore failing.
I'm I correct? Is it a bug in jQuery, or am I being stupid?
How do I resolve this?

Many thanks in advance for all the answers.
Marcin

Comment: Calculate the length of the children dynamically each time, it looks like your reference is based on the original length when the DOM was created and it isn't listening past it. Create a JSFiddle for more help.

Comment: it could be that you are looking at a wrong instance of the `select` element... can you log the value of `$(this.el).children()` and `jQuery("#colourtiles").children()` also `jQuery("#colourtiles").is(this.el)`

Comment: @scrowler how to I calculate it dynamically? My reference is based on the right thing, the 'el' object holds the entire set of `option`'s, so 219 items (216 generated, 3 static), but .length is 3... it looks like jQuery's .append() is not updating .length.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am looking at the correct instance; I only have one `select` in my HTML.
these are all returning only 3 elements, and `jQuery("#colourtiles").is(this.el)` is true.

When I do `console.log('this.el.children');` I get the full HtmlCollection list, with all 219 `<option>'s`, but I see this at the top: `<HtmlCollection length="3">...</HtmlCollection>`.
So both javascript's foreach, and jQuery selectors are using that value of 3 when returning elements, but why is it 3 after I do .append()? :/

Comment: any more ideas please? still stuck :/

Answer (score 0):

First, I would append each option like this

```
 $("<option/>")
    .val(__hex_value)
    .data("class",_cbtn.substring(1, 13))
    .html(__hex_value)
    .appendTo("#colourtiles");
```

I don't know what `el` is in your code so I can't really give more of an answer on this, but if you want to loop through each option in that select, use `.each()` and it will include what you did in the DOM:

```
$("option","#colourtiles").each(function(i,v){
  ...
});
```

Comment: `el` is an object containing the list of all `[object HTMLOptionElement]`'s.
Your suggestion doesn't work I'm afraid, still .length = 3.
Also, I would rather not use jQuery in the second script (the one containing `[].slice...` -- it's not my script, and it's jQuery-free, so would prefer to keep it this way. But will change if needed of course...

Comment: I can only think of one problem here that is causing your 2nd script not being able to see the updated DOM--How you have it arranged.  What is your 2nd script supposed to do anyway?

Comment: the script is generating colour boxes, effectively a colour picker.
I am calling console.log from that very script, and from that very script I can see all the elements, but the list length is 3. Any ideas as to why?